How to get the most recent date in a new column from a group of rows in PowerBI
I have a row of four different dates, and I want to create my own column that can show the most recent of those four dates in PowerBI. How can I do this?
I’ve tried the max function and I get too many arguments. Has to be easily done, but I can not figure it out. enter image description here
Sample Data

Can you give sample data?

yes entered above

it should work for all the columns.
Column = max(max(max('Table'[Email],'Table'[Sales]),'Table'[Market]),'Table'[Call])
pls try again.


pls try this
Column = MAX (
    MAX ( MAX ( 'Table'[column1], 'Table'[column2] ), 'Table'[column3] ),
    'Table'[column4]
)



I think that’s only including the first and fourth row. Everytime I attempt to do it with data that the max is in the second or third column, it doesn’t generate it. Maybe I should send more sample data where the max isn’t in the first or fourth column?

I added new sample data at the top that should better reflect my problem.
